# Finding a predictable process $\lambda$ such that $dA_t = d\langle M \rangle_t \lambda_t$ where $Y = M + A$ is an exponential Lévy process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, levy-processes

Assume $X$ is a finite-variation Lévy process and let $Y_t = e^{X_t}$. It can be shown that one can decompose $Y_t$ as $Y_t = M_t + A_t$ where $M$ is a local martingale and $A$ is continuous and finite variation. Am trying to verify whether there exists a predictable process $\lambda$ such that
$$
dA_t = d\langle M \rangle_t \lambda_t\tag1
$$
where $\langle M \rangle$ is the predictable quadratic variation process. From what I have found, $A$ and $M$ have the following expressions:
$$
A_t = \int^t_0 Y_{s-} \alpha\, \mathrm ds, \qquad \langle M \rangle_t = \int^t_0 Y^2_{s-} \beta\, \mathrm ds
$$
for constatnts $\alpha, \beta$. But then, $(1)$ seems to become
$$
\alpha = \beta Y_t\lambda_t \Leftrightarrow \lambda_t = \frac{\alpha\beta^{-1}}{Y_t}
$$
but $Y_t$ is not predictable, which seems to imply that it does not exist such a predictable process $\lambda_t$ that satisfies $(1)$.

I am pretty sure about the expressions of $A_t$ and $\langle M\rangle$ but I was somewhat surprised by the conclusion which I fear might be incorrect. I would be very grateful if someone could verify whether my analysis is correct.

Comment: Why not take $\lambda_t = \alpha\beta^{-1}Y^{-1}_{t-}$?

Comment: @JohnDawkins I am probably missing something important, but I don't see the difference between that and the one I wrote. Is $Y_{t-}$ $\{ \mathcal {F}^X_t\}$-predictable?

Comment: Yes, $Y_{t-}$ is adapted and left-continuous, hence predictable.  And $\int_0^t Y_{s}^2\,ds =\int_0^t Y_{s-}^2\,ds$ (for all $t\ge 0$) because a cadlag process like $Y$ has at most countably many jumps.

Comment: @JohnDawkins That is very enlightening. If you wish to post it as an answer I am more than happy to accept it. Either way, thank you.